# sqlalchemy: Call STR_TO_DATE on column

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I am moving some of my code onto sqlalchemy from using raw MySQL queries.

The current issue I am having is that the datetime was saved in a string format by a C# tool. Unfortunately, the representation does not match up with Python's (as well as that it has an extra set of single quotes), thus making filtering somewhat cumbersome.

Here is an example of the format that the date was saved in:

```
'2016-07-01T17:27:01'
```

Which I was able to convert to a usable datetime using the following MySQL command:

```
 STR_TO_DATE(T.PredicationGeneratedTime, \"'%%Y-%%m-%%dT%%H:%%i:%%s'\")
```

However, I cannot find any documentation that describes how to invoke built-in functions such as STR_TO_DATE when filtering with sqlalchemy

The following Python code:

```
 session.query(Train.Model).filter(cast(Train.Model.PredicationGeneratedTime, date) < start)
```

is giving me:

```
 TypeError: Required argument 'year' (pos 1) not found
```

There does not seem to be a way to specify the format for the conversion.

Note: I realize the solution is to fix the way the datetime is stored, but in the mean time I'd like to run queries against the existing data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `cast()` you should be using `sqlalchemy.DateTime`, not (what I assume is) a `datetime.date` - that is the cause of the exception.

However, fixing that will not really help because of the embedded single quotes.

You are fortunate that the dates stored in your table are in ISO format. That means that lexicographic comparisons will work on the date strings themselves, without casting. As long as you use a string for `start` with the surrounding single quotes, it will work.

```
from datetime import datetime

start = "'{}'".format(datetime.now().isoformat())
session.query(Train.Model).filter(Train.Model.PredicationGeneratedTime < start)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use `func.str_to_date(COLUMN, FORMAT_STRING)` instead of `cast`